# Calculate the time for progress bar is finished and throw warning if it takes too long?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I am automating a file upload on a web page.
The point of my automation is to check if the file upload is taking longer than expected.

This is the hmtl for the progress upload bar banner:

```
<div _ngcontent-rqo-c295="" class="upload-box-title"> 
  "Uploading List: 0/0"
  <label _ngcontent-rqo-c295="" class="ui label mini right clear-label" style="margin-right: 1px;">CLEAR</label>
</div>
```

When the process is completed, the "uploading list" text will go from "0/0" (before uploading) to "0/1" while uploading 1 file, the only case i will be testing) to "1/1" , when the upload is completed.

I have 3 questions:

- How can I check for the change in that text
- How can I get the time between "0/0" and "1/1"?
- Can I do an Assert with the time? Saying i know how long it should take when working properly and in case it takes longer it throws a warning?

Thank you for the help. I am coding in C# and Selenium. I am uploading the file with `Process.Start("\upload.exe")`. The .exe is a script done with AutoItX3.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check for the change in that text

You can wait for the visibility of the text in a particular web element

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(myElement, "1/1"));
```

You can find the C# documentation [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm).
[image]

> How can I get the time between "0/0" and "1/1"?

You can use [Stopwatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) to get the current time.

```
var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
performTheFileUpload();
watch.Stop();
var elapsedTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Can I do an Assert with the time? Saying I know how long it should take when working properly and in case it takes longer it throws a warning?

Sure, *watch.ElapsedMilliseconds* is a *long*. You can assert against it as you do with any other *long*.